# Doctrine Email Validation triggers on empty form field

Tags: validation, symfony1, doctrine

I don't want an empty email field in my form to trigger a 
Doctrine_Validator_Exception. But, since Doctrine_Validator_Email uses 
"is_null()" to check for empty (non-existing) values (and the POST 
['email'] contains an empty string), it does.

Is this correct? Is there a simple way around this?

This also has an impact when trying to set a column as unique (trying 
to store a second empty string in the column triggers the validator).

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance, 
Erland Wiencke

(Symfony 1.4.1/Doctrine 1.2)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem in our Doctrine 1.2 application. In my case, the fix ended up adding this workaround to the record's `merge()` method:

```
    $this->email = trim($this->email);
    if ($this->email == '') {
        $this->email = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, not tested, but seem to work alltogether or separately:

1) `$this->validatorSchema['email'] = null;`

or

2) `$this->validatorSchema['email'] = sfValidatorPass();`

or

3) `$this->validatorSchema->setOption('allow_extra_fields', true);`

or

4) Just set `required` attribute to `false`:

```
$this->widgetSchema['email'] = sfWidgetFormInputText(array('required' => false));
```

Comment: Thanks, but the sf validators are not the issue. There also appears to be a couple of errors in your example ('required' option on a widget being one).